# Unable to get the right output using pattern matcher

Tags: java, matcher

I want to get the value of id field in below string where the value of inuse field is 1 .

```
          "version": "IPv6",
              "primarywins": null,
              "id": 3,
              "updated": 1368803376681,
              "description": null,
              "inuse": 0,
              "alias": "Shared MGMT"
           },
           {
              "computernameprefix": null,
              "protocol": "static",
              "version": "IPv4",
              "primarywins": null,
              "id": 5,
              "updated": 1368912314856,
              "description": null,
              "inuse": 1
```

I am trying below java code

```
String regex = "\"id\": ([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]),\n.*,\n.*,\n.*\"inuse\": 1";
Pattern index_pattern2 = Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher cMatcher2 = index_pattern2.matcher(The string mentioned above);
     if(cMatcher2 != null && cMatcher2.find()
      {
        ipGrp = cMatcher2.group(1);
      }
```

The value of ipGrp from the above code is always 3, whereas I would like to get the value as 5
Any suggestion as to how can I get the value of correct id field when the value of in use is 1

Comment: Looks like JSON.  Why not use a JSON library?

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex instead:

```
"id": ([0-9]{1,4})[^}]*"inuse": 1
```

Escaped:

```
"\"id\": ([0-9]{1,4})[^}]*\"inuse\": 1"
```

What did I do here?

1. Change `[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` into `[0-9]{1,4}`, which means there must be between 1 and 4 of `[0-9]`.
2. Change `,\n.*,\n.*,\n.*` to `[^}]*`, which means any characters except `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
(?s)"id":\s?(\d+),+.*?(?:"inuse":\s)(\d)
```

It captures both inactive and active, but you can filter the results. (?s) causes "." to capture newlines. The first capture group captures the id. The (?: cause the second group to be non-capturing. The second capture group captures the active flag. Good luck.